# how to "rename" an xml element

Tags: java, dom

I have trouble moving a node contents(all its children) to another one (edit: with the order being kept):

```
Document document = pathoNode.getOwnerDocument();
Element renamedNode = document.createElement("PATHO");
NodeList children = pathoNode.getChildNodes();
for ( int i=0 ; i<children.getLength() ; i++ ) {
    Node nodeToAdd = children.item(i);
    renamedNode.appendChild( nodeToAdd );
}
```

When I call `.appendChild( nodeToAdd )`, the node is removed from `pathoNode`, but also from the `NodeList` returned by `getChildNodes()`.

So, the number returned by `children.getLength()` will decrease each time we iterate, and the algorithm will miss one on two elements.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with "copying" and not moving nodes, you just pass a deeply copied node:

```
NodeList children = pathoNode.getChildNodes();
for ( int i=0 ; i<children.getLength() ; i++ ) {
    Node nodeToAdd = children.item(i);
    renamedNode.appendChild( nodeToAdd.cloneNode(true) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go backwards through the collection:

```
for ( int i=children.getLength() - 1; i>=0 ; i-- ) {
    Node nodeToAdd = children.item(i);
    renamedNode.appendChild( nodeToAdd );
}
```

Comment: I need the order to be kept, I'm pretty sure this solution reverses it.

Comment: (I still gave you +1, cause I forgot to mention that initially)